# Which dual monitor mount/arm to go over a 43" monitor

Tags: monitors, displays, multiple-monitors, monitor-stand

I'm using a 43" monitor (stands 62 centimetres tall off the desk) and want a dual monitor arm to go above it, but many brands are too short. What dual monitor arm/mount can lift the two screens high enough above the 43" monitor I have, so that they're not obstructed?